# Scala Play 2, passing request to method

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a `Play 2.0` app

`TestController.scala`

```
def foo(p1: String) = Action {implicit request =>
  Ok(bar(p1))
}

private def bar(p1: String) = {
//access request parameter here
}
```

Is there a way to use `implicit` to pass `request` to `bar`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
  def foo(p1: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(bar(p1))
  }

  private def bar(p1: String)(implicit req: RequestHeader) = "content"
```

The code:

```
Action { implicit request
```

Calls this method on the Action object:

```
def apply(block: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
```

So, what you called "request" matches the paramater named "block".  The "implicit" here is optional: it makes the "request" value available as an implicit parameter to other method/function calls.

The implicit in your "bar" function says that it can take the value of "req" from an implicit value, and doesn't necessarily need to be passed in explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that works. Follow up question, does the implicit need to be passed as a curried parameter?

Comment: In scala, it the the parameter _list_, not the parameter, that is implicit.  I'm not sure of the motivation for that.

Comment: scala> implicit val i = 1
i: Int = 1

scala> implicit val s = "hi"
s: java.lang.String = hi

scala> def concat(implicit x:Int, y:String) = x + y
concat: (implicit x: Int, implicit y: String)String

scala> concat
res0: String = 1hi

Comment: With play 2.0.3 I kept getting "Cannot find any HTTP Request here" when I did `def foo[A](i: Int)(implicit request: Request[A]): Baz = { ... }`.  This error was fixed by changing `Request[A]` to instead use `RequestHeader`.  Thanks Adam Rabung- your info was a big help.

Comment: With play 2.4.6, I need to use Request[AnyContent]