# scala play 2.0 get request header

Tags: scala, playframework, http-headers, httprequest

I am converting some of my java code to scala and I would like to be able to get a specific header and return it as a string.

In java I have:

```
return request().getHeader("myHeader")
```

I have been unable to achieve the same thing in scala. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198998/scala-play-2-passing-request-to-method

also see comments below Travis Brown's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write:

```
request.get("myHeader").orNull
```

If you wanted something essentially the same as your Java line. But you don't!

`request.get("myHeader")` returns an [`Option[String]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html), which is Scala's way of encouraging you to write code that won't throw null pointer exceptions.

You can process the `Option` in various ways. For example, if you wanted to supply a default value:

```
val h: String = request.get("myHeader").getOrElse("")
```

Or if you want to do something with the header if it exists:

```
request.foreach { h: String => doSomething(h) }
```

Or just:

```
request foreach doSomething
```

See [this cheat sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/) for more possibilities.

Comment: Thanks much! noted that I should handle the null/Option case as well. Perhaps I'm having a more basic issue. I'm getting the error "not found: value request".

Comment: Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: In one of my controller files, in a very basic method:
def getName = request.get("myHeader")

Comment: Using this class (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Request.html). If I try to do: println(play.mvc.Http.Request.getHeader("MyHeader")), it will error with the message: "value getHeader is not a member of object play.mvc.Http.Request". Is there a reason I can't use this java object?

Comment: That `getHeader` method isn't static. You probably want to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11198998/334519).

Comment: Should this be `request.headers` instead of just `request`?

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer doesn't work for scala with playframework 2.2:

```
request.get("myHeader").getOrElse("")
```

It gives me the below error:

> value get is not a member of
> play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]

use below

```
request.headers.get("myHeader").getOrElse("")
```